# Modeling Complicated Wheel

Tags: modeling

I'm currently modeling a Golf GTI 2018 in Blender, and have come down to modeling the wheels. I'm currently using Blue Inversion's tutorial, and I just can't find a way to get the way the GTI's wheels look. The way that the "spokes" or whatever they're called come out not straight but each slanted like a throwing star or something of the type.

I was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to model the wheel. Any tutorial on Youtube I search up have the spokes coming straight out.

[Blue Inversion's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vFkGh179H0)

[image: GolfGTI Wheel]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

1. Make a circle with 5 vertices.
2. Duplicate it (in Edit Mode, so it's the same object) and scale up. Rotate the outer circle.
3. Select all Edges and subdivide.
4. Make faces following the pattern shown.
5. You're done- you can adjust/tweak/whatever now