# Modeling Complicated Wheel (2)

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm currently working on modeling a Golf GTI wheel in Blender, but I'm a beginner and was wondering how I should move on from here.

Attached it a picture of my progress and was wondering how I should go about creating these knife-like pieces that extrude from the hub of the wheel.

[image: Modeled Wheel]

After this how am I supposed to attach the "spokes" to the outer wheel? Should I be using the subdivision modifier on the spokes?

Thank you for your help, let me know if I need to clear anything up. :)

Link to my first post on this question: [Modeling Complicated Wheel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/256405/modeling-complicated-wheel)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the *Array* modifier with an empty as *Object Offset* that you rotate 72° so that it makes the object instances rotate 360°. This way you just need to work on the original object and make sure that all the instances stick to each other:

[image]